# Can someone tell me what is next in that 3 sequences?

Tags: pattern, number-sequence

I'm looking at three sequences from the test at http://free.ultimaiq.net/nse.htm. I managed to answer 27 of the 30 questions, but I'm really curious about the other three.

Q6: 1001, 4524, 4299, 3984, ? -- here is something like 
100 145 244 299 398 45+99+55+99 and the next one should be 398+65and+99 but its not

Q24: 50625, 1296, 8100, 3240, ? -- I only know that the answer is not an integer and there is a hint "think how you can arrive at an+2 given an+1 and an".

Q22: 38, 50, 22, 18, ?, ?

Comment: Q22 has the property that if you count the 7-segment LED bits set, you get 12,11,10,9, but I can't see any reason behind the choices.

Comment: Yes i try many combination's to solve this question and still but thank you for that  2Q.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Q6:

> The answer is 4354, which is +45,+99,+55,+99,+45,+99, so 443,542 splits into the 4-digit 4354.

Q24:

> $50625=2^03^45^4$
>  $1296=2^43^45^0$
>  $8100=2^23^45^2$
>  $3240=2^33^45^1$
>
>  The power of $3$ stays constant, the powers of $2$ and $5$ are the average of the previous two, so the answer is $2^{2.5}3^45^{1.5}=5122.889809472774517838207541981$, although anything with 1dp or more seems to work.

Comment: This is pretty stupid. (I don't mean that your answer is wrong, I mean the _question_ is stupid.) Quite aside from the gratuitous "frame shifting", this boils down to asking the solver to extrapolate the sequence 45, 55, ? which could perfectly well yield 65 (OP's guess), 66 (triangular numbers), 45 (your answer), and any number of other roughly equally plausible possibilities. [EDITED to add:] I'm referring to Q6. Q24 is more reasonable.

Comment: @JMP The much simpler way to explain the solution for Q24 is that `a_n = sqrt(a_n-1 * a_n-2)` (i.e. the geometric mean).

Answer (score 1):

NSE IQ # 22:

> 38 50 22 18.

Answers:

> to resolve the quest you have to add two number and then divide for four. you add 38+50= 88/4= 22 ( it's the third number). 50+22= 72/4=18 ( the fourth number). 22+18=40/4= 10 then 18+10=28/4=7. so the answer is 10 and 7.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! Unfortunately, your answer lacks an explanation of why you think it is correct, so may be deleted. Answers should be a thoughtfully considered attempt to solve the puzzle that was posed, with an explanation of how you arrived at the solution and/or why you believe your solution is correct. We're looking for quality answers, not a one-line response containing the first thing that leapt to mind. Please take some time to look around and familiarize yourself with the kinds of answers that are well-received here, ideally before you post any more answers.